# Padding return values MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, css, sql, return-value

I have a  formfield where I can put in a number. That number is saved in MySQL database, and returned in my div tag:

```
<div id="returnnumber">

</div>
```

I would like a padding on some of the numbers here. Fx:

```
If the number is 1 -> padding-left : 30px;
If the number is 3 -> padding-left : 50px;
If the number is 7 -> padding left : 40px;
```

This is just some examples. The main problem is, how can I give some specifik numbers a padding?

Best Regard
Nekr

Comment: You can't use a number for a DOM id, it is invalid.

Comment: I think you can use class for different number, eg. `<div class="div_X"></div>` where X is the value from the form, so you format the div using CSS class selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
foreach($pad_numbers_array as $pad_number)
{
?>
<div class="padding_<?php echo $pad_number; ?>"></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now in css:

```
.padding_1
{
    padding-left: 30;
}
.padding_3
{
    padding-left: 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want this. Lets say i got a number from the db, $padding_number;

```
$style = '';

if($padding_number == '1'){
   $style = 'style="padding-left : 30px"';
}

if($padding_number == '3'){
$style = 'style="padding-left : 50px"';
}

if($padding_number == '7'){
$style = 'style="padding-left : 40px"';
}

<div id="returnnumber" <?php echo $style ?>>
     //your code here
</div>
```

*** UPDATE ON QUESTION ***

What is I wanted `1, 3, 5, 7, 9` etc had a padding-left: 20px;
and              `2, 4, 6, 8, 10` etc had a padding-left: 40px;

Could I optimize the code a little bit, instead of use

```
if($padding_number == '1') {
  $style = 'style="padding-left : 30px"';
}

if($padding_number == '3') {
  $style = 'style="padding-left : 30px"';
}
```

If I fx had to get up to 100 numbers.

Here is my update answer according to your requirments :

```
$style = '';

if($padding_number%2 == '0'){
   $style = 'style="padding-left : 40px"';
}else{
   $style = 'style="padding-left : 20px"';
 }

<div id="returnnumber" <?php echo $style ?>>
     //your code here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maha Dev. I will try that when I come home from work. Then I will give som feedback.
Best Regards

Comment: @NeKr you mean, you want different padding for even and odd numbers, right?

Comment: Hello Maha. It is actually some specifik numbers. So it is not only even and uneven numbers. Maybe I wrote it a little bit cryptic

Comment: Then you have to save every padding inside your database along with the dynamic number you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$styles = array();
$styles[1] = 30;
$styles[3] = 50;
$styles[7] = 40;
$paddingLeft = isset($styles[$YOURVARIABLE]) ? $styles[$YOURVARIABLE] : 0;
?>
<div id="returnnumber" style="padding-left:<?php echo $paddingLeft ?>">
</div>
```

Take an array of paddings.

And append values to it.

If you want to add another condition you can add another array element easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pupil. I will try that when I come home from work. Then I will give som feedback.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "number_"."<?php echo $returned_value ?>">
</div>
```

Then apply style to that class :

```
<style>
.number_10{
padding-left : "5px"
}
.number_5{
padding-right : "5px"
}
</style>
```